# iPhone 5 (4") back screen appearing at the bottom of the screen on the click of the button

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, uibutton, iphone-5, ios6.1

Hey this may be a duplicate question but trust me i have tried every single option that was answered previously to the similar questions but nothing turned out to be useful.
I am making an application iPhone 5 compatible. Everything works fine until i click on the UIButton. The black View appears at the bottom of the screen. Heres a screenShot.

- Before click on the button

  https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACBUr.png
- Black screen appears after the click

  https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wKNX.png

I am not using window.xib hence i set

> self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];

I added the Default screen correctly. Everything is working just fine except this part. Do known where am I going wrong.

Comment: this is the what happens after the CANCEL button is clicked http://i.stack.imgur.com/h8rHU.png

Comment: in xib use springs and truts to autoresize

Comment: AUTOSIZING is also set correctly.But it is of no help at this point.

Comment: in view did load try to set frame self.view.frame=[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds]; try this and let me know

Comment: Me also had same problem resized xib controls ans for hardcode frame i checked manually with mainscreen frame.and do one thing in all ViewController XIB check property of size in propert window and make all to freeform from 4 inch /3.5 inch